# How to find the distribution of a column in PySpark dataframe for all the unique values present in that column?

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have a PySpark dataframe-

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([
    ("u1", 0),
    ("u2", 0),
    ("u3", 1),
    ("u4", 2),
    ("u5", 3),
    ("u6", 2),],
    ['user_id', 'medals'])

df.show()
```

Output-

```
+-------+------+
|user_id|medals|
+-------+------+
|     u1|     0|
|     u2|     0|
|     u3|     1|
|     u4|     2|
|     u5|     3|
|     u6|     2|
+-------+------+
```

I want to get the distribution of the **medals** column for all the users. So if there are n unique values in the **medals** column, I want n columns in the output dataframe with corresponding number of users who received that many medals.

The output for the data given above should look like-

```
+------- +--------+--------+--------+
|medals_0|medals_1|medals_2|medals_3|
+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|       2|       1|       2|       1|
+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it's a simple [`pivot`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.4/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.GroupedData.pivot):

```py
df.groupBy().pivot("medals").count().show()

+---+---+---+---+
|  0|  1|  2|  3|
+---+---+---+---+
|  2|  1|  2|  1|
+---+---+---+---+
```

---

if you need some *cosmetic* to add the word **medals** in the column name, then you can do this :

```py
medals_df = df.groupBy().pivot("medals").count()

for col in medals_df.columns:
    medals_df = medals_df.withColumnRenamed(col, "medals_{}".format(col))

medals_df.show()

+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|medals_0|medals_1|medals_2|medals_3|
+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|       2|       1|       2|       1|
+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```